# Why would selenium take 5 times slower to run a webassembly powered app than a manual test?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webassembly

I was testing a web app that utilizes the Vue.js framework and runs WebAssembly binary behind the scene. It takes significantly slower to run the exact same task using selenium from python and google chrome driver than it is to manually start the task. And I'm not talking about detecting any elements on the page, etc. I'm specifically referring to the execution time of running the wasm module itself (the web app reports the execution time). Any ideas why that would be? I'm using Fedora Linux 32 and it's the latest distribution update of Google Chrome 90.0.4430.85 (Official Build) (64-bit) (hence the web driver is also version 90 I believe).
P.S. This is the application that I was referring to:
https://durrantlab.pitt.edu/webina/

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
import argparse
from pathlib import Path
 
def dir_path(string):
    if Path(string).exists():
        return Path(string).resolve()
    else:
        raise FileNotFoundError(string)
 
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Pass arguments to feed to webina.')
parser.add_argument('--receptor', type=dir_path, required=True)
parser.add_argument('--ligand', type=dir_path, required=True)
parser.add_argument('--center_x', type=float, required=True)
parser.add_argument('--center_y', type=float, required=True)
parser.add_argument('--center_z', type=float, required=True)
parser.add_argument('--size_x', type=float, required=True)
parser.add_argument('--size_y', type=float, required=True)
parser.add_argument('--size_z', type=float, required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
 
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
 
browser.get('https://durrantlab.pitt.edu/webina/')
 
receptor_file = browser.find_element_by_id('__BVID__16')
lignad_file = browser.find_element_by_id('__BVID__20')
center_x = browser.find_element_by_id('center_x')
center_y = browser.find_element_by_id('center_y')
center_z = browser.find_element_by_id('center_z')
size_x = browser.find_element_by_id('size_x')
size_y = browser.find_element_by_id('size_y')
size_z = browser.find_element_by_id('size_z')
start_webina = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Start Webina')]")
 
center_x.send_keys(repr(args.center_x))
center_y.send_keys(repr(args.center_y))
center_z.send_keys(repr(args.center_z))
size_x.send_keys(repr(args.size_x))
size_y.send_keys(repr(args.size_y))
size_z.send_keys(repr(args.size_z))
receptor_file.send_keys(str(args.receptor))
lignad_file.send_keys(str(args.ligand))
 
start_webina.click()
 
 
WebDriverWait(browser, 100000).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Standard Output')]/../div/button")))
standard_download = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Standard Output')]/../div/button")
standard_download.click()
pdbqt_download = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Output PDBQT')]/../div/button").click()
browser.implicitly_wait(5)
browser.quit()
```

Comment: remove sleep() and replace them with implicit waits at least. Without seeing code it's difficult to answer.

Comment: Hello, vitaliis. I do use the implicit waits. Here's the code:
https://pastebin.com/2c8t9qN7
Once again, it's literally the execution time of the binary that is slower when started by selenium.

Comment: what does the wasm do?  Maybe post that code...  your code seems like it could be the issue because you are mixing explicit and implicit waits... and your explicit timeout period is very large.  Don't mix implicit/explicit waits... use one or the other or you'll have competing polling loops that can interfere with each other.

Comment: You did not add language tag, your code is in Python

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not correctly work with few fields.

Check how fast this is and fix your locators.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get('https://durrantlab.pitt.edu/webina/')
browser.implicitly_wait(15)
# receptor_file = browser.find_element_by_id('__BVID__16')
# lignad_file = browser.find_element_by_id('__BVID__20')
center_x = browser.find_element_by_id('center_x')
center_y = browser.find_element_by_id('center_y')
center_z = browser.find_element_by_id('center_z')
size_x = browser.find_element_by_id('size_x')
size_y = browser.find_element_by_id('size_y')
size_z = browser.find_element_by_id('size_z')
start_webina = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Start Webina')]")

center_x.send_keys("test")
center_y.send_keys("test")
center_z.send_keys("test")
size_x.send_keys("test")
size_y.send_keys("test")
size_z.send_keys("test")

start_webina.click()  

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Standard Output')]/../div/button")))  # Here will be thrown timeout because element is not found
standard_download = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Standard Output')]/../div/button")
standard_download.click()
pdbqt_download = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Output PDBQT')]/../div/button").click()
browser.quit()
```

Site will not let actions after`start_webina.click()` because some fields are not set.

**Answering to your question**: tests are slow because of `WebDriverWait(browser, 100000).` **100000!!** seconds timeout is a little big, don't you think so?

Also note where I set implicit wait and where you do it.

**Edit**:
You add some files there. Try adding `time.wait()` after they are uploaded. Wait time depends on how much time it takes to upload. Afterwards replace this time with explicit wait.

I think that you also have issues with uploading files, verify it. But it is a different question.

Comment: is there webassembly version of Selenium? got any links??